# Remove black bar effect in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am starting to use PhpStorm, and from time to time, I get a black bar on the line I am editing. It masks everything before it and I cannot read what I write because of it. I have no idea why it turn on, and it make it hard to code when you can't see what you just wrote. Here's an example:

[image: Black bar]

For those curious, it is hiding a simple `<h1>home</1>`. I have no idea why it trigger and it's driving me mad.

Comment: Is color scheme set to Default in File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme? What about custom plugins in File | Settings | Plugins?

Comment: Color scheme is default and custom plugins return no plugin found. When I restart phpstorm, it is fixed, but it always come back. And as my PC is extremely slow, it takes 1 or 2 minutes to start phpstorm, I'd rather not have to restart every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! Researched a bit - this looks like Java/OS issues with rendering. Do you have several graphic adapters at your workstation? Do other Java/Swing-based editors like JEdit or Netbeans behave in the same way?

Comment: Nope, nothing else than the standard stuff on that computer. The only other editor I ever used on that computer are notepad++, visual studio 2017 and visual studio code. None of them have that problem.

Comment: Would be great if you could check how http://jedit.org behaves on your system. The investigation for a similar case is on-going at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191882 - please leave a comment there to help with troubleshooting.